# Help with hiding DIV tags, based on text content, using Greasemonkey

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey

I am looking for a way to write a Greasemonkey script which will take the following snippet of code and only show the code blocks consisting of `<div class="A"` where both "passtest" and "State1" are present.

```
<div class="A">
    <div class="B">
        <a href="/link1">
        <img class="imgClass" src="http://link.com/img.img" title="imgTitle"/>
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="C">
        <span class="sc1">passtest</span>
        <br/>
        <em class="ec1">City1, State1</em>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="A">
    <div class="B">
        <a href="/link1">
        <img class="imgClass" src="http://link.com/img.img" title="imgTitle"/>
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="C">
        <span class="sc1">failtest </span>
        <br/>
        <em class="ec1">City1, State1 </em>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="A">
    <div class="B">
        <a href="/link1">
        <img class="imgClass" src="http://link.com/img.img" title="imgTitle"/>
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="C">
        <span class="sc1">passtest </span>
        <br/>
        <em class="ec1">City2, State2 </em>
    </div>
</div>
```

---

I found this from ***Dive Into Greasemonkey***:

```
var allDivs, thisDiv;
allDivs = document.evaluate("//div[@class='sponsoredlink']", document, null, XPathResult.UNORDERED_NODE_SNAPSHOT_TYPE, null);
for (var i = 0; i < allDivs.snapshotLength; i++) {
    thisDiv = allDivs.snapshotItem(i); 
    // do something with thisDiv 
}
```

I am looking at this code as the starting point for what I want to do. But, I am just a user, not a coder.

I understand the logic I need is:
For each div where class="a" which does contain the text "passtest" and also does not contain "state1" do not display that div.

Comment: @jared-farrish  
  
From Dive Into Greasemonkey:  
var allDivs, thisDiv;
allDivs = document.evaluate(
"//div[@class='sponsoredlink']",
document,
null,
XPathResult.UNORDERED_NODE_SNAPSHOT_TYPE,
null);
for (var i = 0; i < allDivs.snapshotLength; i++) {
thisDiv = allDivs.snapshotItem(i);
// do something with thisDiv
}  I am looking at this code as the starting point for what I want to do.  
  
But, I am just a user, not a coder.  
  
I understand the logic I need is:  
for each div where class="a" which does contain the text "passtest" and also does not contain "state1" do not display that div.

Comment: Also I seem to be having trouble with the "mini-Markdown" formatting, I apologize I couldn't make my previous post more readable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a script that does that, using [jQuery](http://jquery.com/).  The hard part is choosing [the selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/).

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name     Show State1 passes only.
// @include  http://YOUR_SITE/YOUR_PATH/*
// @require  http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js
// ==/UserScript==

$("div.A")  .hide ()
            .has ("span.sc1:contains('passtest')")
            .has ("em.ec1:contains('State1')")
            .show ();
```

Note that [`:contains()` is case-sensitive](http://www.jqapi.com/#p=contains-selector).

[**See the code in action at jsFiddle.**](http://jsfiddle.net/XxDXL/)

Comment: Solved! Thank you so very much, this did precisely what I needed it to do, I simply cannot thank you enough!