# Hide a div based on a specific text contained within H4 tag

Tags: jquery, text, show-hide, tampermonkey

The html below is a condensed version of the Clicky.com home dashboard, I am looking to hide the forums `div` tag altogether that has an `H4` tag containing the phrase "Clicky Forums".

```html
<div class="fl small nounderline nowrap">
    <h4 class="inline">Clicky Forums</h4> &nbsp;
    <a class="no-ajax" href="/forums/">See more...</a>
    <br>&nbsp; &nbsp;
    <span class="">Sep 6</span>&nbsp;
    <a class="no-ajax" href="http://clicky.com/forums/?id=18929">Adding goal to form submission javascrip...</a>
    <br>&nbsp; &nbsp;
    <span class="">Sep 5</span>&nbsp;
    <a class="no-ajax" href="http://clicky.com/forums/?id=18928">no show visitor statistic</a>
    <br>&nbsp; &nbsp;
    <span class="">Sep 3</span>&nbsp;
    <a class="no-ajax" href="http://clicky.com/forums/?id=18924">Number of new visitors per url in a spec...</a>
    <br>
</div>
```

Comment: [Help with hiding DIV tags, based on text content, using Greasemonkey](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6921491)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use JQuery to find all `<h4>` tags then check each one's `.text()` for a match. If found, `.hide()` the element's `.parent()` container.

```js
$('h4').each(function() {
  $el = $(this);
  
  if ($el.text() === 'Clicky Forums') {
    $el.parent().hide(); // or .remove()
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>Stuff before</p>

<div class="fl small nounderline nowrap">
    <h4 class="inline">Clicky Forums</h4> &nbsp;
    <a class="no-ajax" href="/forums/">See more...</a>
    <br>&nbsp; &nbsp;
    <span class="">Sep 6</span>&nbsp;
    <a class="no-ajax" href="http://clicky.com/forums/?id=18929">Adding goal to form submission javascrip...</a>
    <br>&nbsp; &nbsp;
    <span class="">Sep 5</span>&nbsp;
    <a class="no-ajax" href="http://clicky.com/forums/?id=18928">no show visitor statistic</a>
    <br>&nbsp; &nbsp;
    <span class="">Sep 3</span>&nbsp;
    <a class="no-ajax" href="http://clicky.com/forums/?id=18924">Number of new visitors per url in a spec...</a>
    <br>
</div>

<p>Stuff after</p>
```

Note that this only hides the forum elements, you could also use `.remove()` to completely take them out of the DOM.

Also note that this is a fairly fragile solution and can break if the title of the section changes **at all** (a single letter or capital difference will break the query). I'd recommend trying to find some more specific selector, like an ID, to identify the forum container.

Comment: You Mr.Soviut is my true Champion! :) Works like a charm, thanks a ton :)

Comment: This isn't a great way to solve the problem. I'll outline why in the answer

Comment: Sure, yes please! :)

Comment: Sure Sir, but it's not fragile as they tested and found this text to work :) Thank you so much Sir.Soviut :)

Comment: @Eshwar yes it's working, but he mentioned about the selector which you are using to select the element. if a single letter changes in h4 it'll break. that's why the selector used here is fragile.

Answer (score 4):

here is a simple one using jQuery

```
$('h4:contains("Clicky Forums")').parent().hide();
```

Comment: it's `parent` not parents :)

Answer (score 1):

You may simply use:

```
$("div h4:contains('Clicky Forums')").parent().hide()
```

The snippet:

```js
$(function () {
  $("div h4:contains('Clicky Forums')").parent().hide();
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="fl small nounderline nowrap">
    <h4 class="inline">Clicky Forums</h4> &nbsp;
    <a class="no-ajax" href="/forums/">See more...</a>
    <br>&nbsp; &nbsp;
    <span class="">Sep 6</span>&nbsp;
    <a class="no-ajax" href="http://clicky.com/forums/?id=18929">Adding goal to form submission javascrip...</a>
    <br>&nbsp; &nbsp;
    <span class="">Sep 5</span>&nbsp;
    <a class="no-ajax" href="http://clicky.com/forums/?id=18928">no show visitor statistic</a>
    <br>&nbsp; &nbsp;
    <span class="">Sep 3</span>&nbsp;
    <a class="no-ajax" href="http://clicky.com/forums/?id=18924">Number of new visitors per url in a spec...</a>
    <br>
</div>
```